# Multicast delegates: Different behavior when adding method references to a delegate in other methods

Tags: c#, .net

I've the below code which declares a delegate:

```
delegate void EmployeeSalaryCalculated(int idEmp);
```

I've these simple classes:

```
    class Employee
    {
        public void CalculateSalary(int idEmp){}
    }

    class Payroll
    {
        public void EmpSalNotification(int idEmp) { }            

        public void SetMethod(ref EmployeeSalaryCalculated esc)
        {
            esc += this.EmpSalNotification;
        }         
    }

    class HR
    {
        public void EmpSalNotification(int idEmp) { }           

        public void SetMethod(ref EmployeeSalaryCalculated esc)
        {
            esc = this.EmpSalNotification;
        }
    }
```

The below button handler makes use of the above classes:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {              
            Payroll payroll = new Payroll();
            HR hr = new HR();            

            EmployeeSalaryCalculated empSalCalculated = null;
            empSalCalculated += payroll.EmpSalNotification;
            empSalCalculated += hr.EmpSalNotification;

            // This invokes both methods - fine. 
            // empSalCalculated.GetInvocationList() returns 2
            empSalCalculated.Invoke(108);

            EmployeeSalaryCalculated empSalCalculated2 = null;
            payroll.SetMethod(ref empSalCalculated2);
            hr.SetMethod(ref empSalCalculated2);

            // This however, invokes only one method!
            // empSalCalculated2.GetInvocationList() returns 1
            empSalCalculated2.Invoke(108);    
        }
```

Despite passing the delegate object `empSalCalculated2` by ref, it just executes only one function unlike delegate object `empSalCalculated` which executes both functions.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line of `HR.SetMethod` class:

```
esc = this.EmpSalNotification;
```

This line overrides whatever value `esc` previously had. So, given the order in which you are calling `SetMethod` from the objects, `empSalCalculated2` only contains method from `HR` instance, which is executed.

To correct this, you might want to either rewrite `HR.SetMethod`:

```
esc += this.EmpSalNotification;
```

or reverse the order in which `SetMethod` are called:

```
hr.SetMethod(ref empSalCalculated2);
payroll.SetMethod(ref empSalCalculated2);
```

Comment: My bad. How could I miss it? Maybe I've worked just too much for the day. Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a typo in your HR class

```
class HR
    {
        public void EmpSalNotification(int idEmp) { }           

        public void SetMethod(ref EmployeeSalaryCalculated esc)
        {
            // this is =, not +=, so only one ref is held at a time
            esc = this.EmpSalNotification; 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a typo in your code:

```
esc += this.EmpSalNotification;
```

vs

```
 esc = this.EmpSalNotification;
```